# I am getting <__main__.Money object at 0x0000019A33F6F6A0> when i run the program

Tags: python-3.9

```
class Money:
    def __init__(self, value, colour):
        self.value = value
        self.colour = colour

    def color(self):
        print(
            f"The Money is {self} , Value is {self.value} , Color is {self.colour}")


Dollar = Money(1000, "Green")
Dollar.color()
```

I am getting the output as "The Money is <**main**.Money object at 0x0000019A33F6F6A0> , Value is 1000 , Color is Green" . Instead i want the output as "The Money is Dollar , Value is 1000 , Color is Green" . Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

```
class Money:
    def __init__(self, value, colour):
        self.value = value
        self.colour = colour

    def color(self):
        print(f"The Money is {self} , Value is {self.value} , Color is {self.colour}")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Dollar"
```

repr method is used for object representation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the variable's name from the class, and if you can, it is bad practice. You can just specify the type in the constructor:

```py
class Money:
    def __init__(self, value, colour, currency):
        self.value = value
        self.colour = colour
        self.currency = currency 

    def color(self):
        print(
            f"The Money is {self.currency} , Value is {self.value} , Color is {self.colour}")


Dollar = Money(1000, "Green", "Dollar")
Dollar.color()
```